# Proving a function f is one to one if and only if $f(A\bigcap B) = f(A) \bigcap f(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function then $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ for all subsets $A$ and $B$ if and only if $f$ is one to one.

Let $x,y\in A\bigcap B$ where $A\bigcap B$ is not empty and $f(x) = f(y)$

$$x\in A\cap B \rightarrow f(x)\in f(A\cap B) \rightarrow f(x)\in f(A)\cap f(B)$$

$$y\in A\cap B \rightarrow f(y)\in f(A\cap B) \rightarrow f(y)\in f(A)\cap f(B)$$

Since $f(x) = f(y)$ then $f$ is one to one if and only if $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Not sure if this is right at all, if anyone can do a proof of this similar to what I have I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's not correct. To show that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ you have to show that if $x\in f(A\cap B)$ then $x\in f(A)\cap f(B)$ and reciprocally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\Leftarrow)$Take $x,y \in A$ such that $x \neq y$, then $\{x\} \cap \{y\} = \emptyset$ then $\emptyset =f(\emptyset) =  f(\{x\}) \cap f(\{y\})$ then $f(x) \neq f(y)$ and therefore $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: This seems very short is that all you need to prove the statement?

Comment: I didn't want to reapeat Surb's first argument, that is $(\implies)$. Then he decided to give a proof for the second part later.

Answer (score 0):

To analise a little bit more the question. If $A\cap B=\varnothing$ the $A\cap B$ condition just says $f(A)\cap f(B)=\varnothing$, which @Aaron very well used. Now, one can ask for the cases $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$. Here every constant function $f$ verifies the $A\cap B$ non-empty condition, but if $f$ is not constant, that condition implies $f$ is injective. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x\ne y$. If $f$ is not constant there is $z\ne x, y$ with $f(z)\ne f(x)$. Pick $A=\{x,z\}, B=\{y,z\}$. We have
$$
f(A\cap B)=\{f(z)\},\quad f(A)=\{f(x),f(z)\}=\{f(y),f(z)\}=f(B),
$$ 
Hence the $A\cap B$ non-empty condition fails for these sets.